# Bool function in PHP to check if you run the script inside docker

Tags: php, object-oriented, strings, scope, docker

I had to do a CLI script that does something, I also had to add a validation that checks if it runs inside the Docker. After some research I found a solution that people check some processes via `cat /proc/self/cgroup` and then `grep` to search for a `docker` phrase within.

So I ended-up with this method. It works pretty well. Inside docker it returns `true`, while on my local mac it returns `false`.

It's not rocket science however I would like people to take a look and tell me if this is a sufficient method or a completely different approach is better.

```
private function isDocker(): bool
{
    $processStack = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec('cat /proc/self/cgroup'));
    $processStack = array_filter($processStack); // remove empty item made by EOL

    foreach ($processStack as $process) {
        if (strpos($process, 'docker') === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Later call to this script looks like:

```
if ($this->isDocker() === false) {
    throw new \Exception('This helper script can be called only inside Docker container.' . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this simple method, I have a couple thoughts below. Your method seems sufficient; I don't think a completely different approach is necessary, although I question how often this method is called. If it is called more than once per page load/script run, it may be worth memoizing the value once obtained for better performance.

---

Good job utilizing the PHP 7 return type declaration.

---

Because the method utilizes no instance properties or methods, it could be declared as [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods), and possibly [`public`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) so other code could use it, though maybe it is best to leave it as `private` until there is a legitimate need to make it otherwise.

---

While the logic would need to be reversed, [`substr_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) could be used instead of [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos). The difference is likely negligible but you need to ask yourself in which case would you rather have the method return as soon as the string is or isn't found...

```
    foreach ($processStack as $process) {
        if (substr_count($process, 'docker')) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

in my humble opinion, maybe a ...

```
    $processStack = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec('cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep docker'));
    $processStack = array_filter($processStack); 
    return count($processStack) > 0;
```

... would be slightly more straightforward, as this follows the same logic but spares an unnecessary foreach loop and is less verbose; since the OP was checking if the term `docker` was present in the `cgroup` to determine if the script was running in a Docker env.

Using `| grep docker` allows us to have an already filtered process stack; that way we only need to check if the array has a length superior to 0 to achieve the same result: knowing if we are on Docker, hence the `return count($processStack) > 0`

Comment: Please argue: how is using three "external processes" instead of two (or even none…) *more straightforward*?

Comment: hey @greybeard, I edited my answser, hope it's clearer; I did not change the OP logic to verify if in Docker, I just tried to reduce the amount of code, hence the *more straightforward*

Comment: (Well, now it mentions *what* you consider *more straightforward*. But having a *shell* pipe the output of a `cat single_file` to another command uses an extra process if *cat* is not built-in to that shell, given a shell's input redirection mechanism. Then, many commands take *file-name parameters* - including *grep*. The shell could filter the words in /proc/self/cgroup all by itself. [So could PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dir.php), using `class Directory` or `open/read/closedir()`.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this simpler way to detect docker:

```php
private function isDocker(): bool
{
    return is_file("/.dockerenv");
}
```